# atmospheric correction using Grass

Tags: grass-gis, atmospheric-correction

I am using i.atcorr for atmospheric correction in Grass6.4.4. I would like to add Landsat8 sensor to my project(build). If I copy the iwave.cpp file from grass 7, I get error messages. Do I need to compile the entire Grass7 i.atcorr module again for this or is there any alternate?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the error messages?  Also, I doubt a module for Grass 7 will work in Grass 6 as there are many breaking changes between the two.  Can you not use Grass 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to compile the source code since this part is written in C programming language.
I would be willing to backport the improvements from GRASS GIS 7 to 6 if you open an enhancement ticket at http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ requesting this backport.

Comment: thank you . this is the ticket no https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ticket/2717#ticket

Comment: please checkout https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ticket/2717#ticket

Comment: I have submitted the modifications to trac, see my answer in the ticket.

Comment: I checked that one but what ever resultant image i got from 6s out, is not matching with surface reflectance product of the same area of L8 which is downloaded from earthexplorer.i changed iwave.cpp , geometry file, wherever sensor adding items are there. some thing is wrong with reflectance values.